# how to replace emoji in android softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, emoji

To display the emoji button in the soft keyboard I use this in the EditText:

```
android:inputType="textShortMessage"
```

which uses the emoji icons for my device (which may be specific to my carrier/phone model).

I want to use my own set of drawables instead. Is there a way to do this without having to create a completely new soft keyboard?

Comment: Wow, I´ve been looking into many emoji libraries thinking there wasn´t a default emoji keyboard in Android. Event it´s not an answer you saved me like 2 days of work

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any single line solution, maybe there is one at Lollipop as it is shipped with emoticons.

Options:

- Implement a **keyboard** (needs a lot of effort + user to change his default keyboard)
- Implement a **panel/dialog that act as keyboard** (needs less effort)
- **Use** an existing **library** to do so a list of libraries is [**here**](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/33) but you can search for more if you want!

Comment: tried emojicon, still seeing ?? in the EmojiconTextView. I will try the other libs next. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using the EmojiHandler from [here](https://github.com/will5/EMOJITextView):

To get the unicode of the emoji from textual message content:

```
String s = EmojiHandler.decodeJava(content);
// use decoded string to display emoji in TextView, Button, etc                     
textButton.setText(s);
```

To encode the emoji from the softkeyboard and put it into a String:

```
String encodedEmoji = EmojiHandler.encodeJava(msgText);
```